# How can I define Ubuntu workspace configuration as code?

Tags: workspaces, automation

Is there any more or less suitable tooling for the scenario described below?

Imagine the following scenario (upon [this question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/workplace-viewport-scripting), but here Ubuntu-specific):

- You have a standard work environment, 4 virtual desktops and many apps
- On system start, system uses some code representation of this environment and loads all apps etc.; you would just need to login.
- Important is that apps can be served with according resources, e.g. browser opens tabs, terminal can iniate system login, spreadsheet process would open the file..
- How windows are arranged, ideally automatic for best usability, but to make it more simple, you could give preferred screem id, if more than one screen available, and coordinates, I leave it here out for simplicity.

Example of code representation, say in YAML:

```
virtual_desktop:
  id: 1
  apps:
    terminal
      - myhost:22
    browser
      - https://askubuntu.com
      - https://www.example.com
virtual_desktop:
  id: 2
  apps:
    openoffice.calc
     - file://~/my_file.odc
...
```

Value: for more or less standard but complex work environment, you save time required to be able to work every time you start your system. For future use, to instantiate VR working environments.

Comment: A tiling wm such as i3 would provide good scripting capabilities to set up a specific work environment upon start. Less obvious with the "common" desktop environments, apart from some autostarting capabilities (where it is up to the app to remember its last settings).

Comment: thanks! this goes into the required direction. I've found so far this know how article how to setup i3wm with xfce, which might work with my Xubuntu (as it uses xfce already).